# update all table x rows with insert id from table y

Tags: postgresql

I've got table x with many existing rows

`x ( id, name)`

I've got a new table y, which is currently empty, *(all fields have default values)*

`y ( id, uuid )`

I've updated x with a new column y_id

`x ( id, name, y_id )`

I want to populate y for every row in x, and then associate x with y via y.id

This is as close as I've got but this sets all rows of x to have the same y.id.

```
with ys as (
  insert into y(uuid) values(default)
  returning id
)
update x set y_id = ys.id
from ys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to populate "y" for every value of "x".  But then you don't have a way to connect the tables.  But . . .

```
with ys as (
  insert into y
      select   -- this is empty on purpose to put in only default values
      from x;
  returning id
)
update x
    set y_id = yy.id
    from (select x.*, row_number() over (order by x_id) as seqnum
          from x
         ) xx join
         (select ys.*, row_number() over (order by y_id) as seqnum
          from ys
         ) yy
         on xx.seqnum = yy.seqnum
where x.x_id = xx.x_id;
```

What does this do?  The CTE inserts a row into `y` with default values for every row in `x`.  The `insert` then adds a sequence number to the x's and y's so they can be aligned, one row to one row.  That value is then used for the update.

Comment: Damn! yeah that works, impressive!  I need to read up on `over` I haven't used that yet.